# PFObject compare:options:range error when searching parse.com class

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

I am trying to make a search query from a Parse.com class, in my collection view, through a UISearchBar. When I try to search it crashes and gives me the error below. Is there a better way to make a search function to a collection view, and if not, what am I doing wrong?

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFObject compare:options:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1741366c0'
```

Here's the code:

```
@implementation DiscoverViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    filteredContentList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self fetchFeatured];

    _featured = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1000];
}

- (void)fetchFeatured {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Featured"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *posts, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error fetching featured");
        }

        [_featured setArray:posts];
        [_collectionView reloadData];
    }];
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (isSearching) {
        return [filteredContentList count];
    } else {
        return [self.featured count];
    }
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (isSearching) {
        DiscoverTableViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"DiscoverTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        _featuredObject = [_featured objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.name.text = _featuredObject[@"name"];

        [(PFFile*)_featuredObject[@"profilePic"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            cell.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }];

        return cell;
    }
    else {
        DailyDiscoverTableViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"DailyDiscoverTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        _featuredObject = [_featured objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.name.text = _featuredObject[@"name"];

        [(PFFile*)_featuredObject[@"profilePic"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            cell.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }];

        return cell;
    }
}

- (void)searchTableList {
    NSString *searchString = _searchBar.text;

    for (NSString *tempStr in _featured) {
        NSComparisonResult result = [tempStr compare:searchString options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchString length])];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
            [filteredContentList addObject:tempStr];
        }
    }
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    isSearching = YES;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    [filteredContentList removeAllObjects];

    if([searchText length] != 0) {
        isSearching = YES;
        [self searchTableList];
    }
    else {
        isSearching = NO;
    }
    [_collectionView reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Cancel clicked");
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Search Clicked");
    [self searchTableList];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code block:

```
for (NSString *tempStr in _featured) {
        NSComparisonResult result = [tempStr compare:searchString options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchString length])];
    if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
        [filteredContentList addObject:tempStr];
    }
}
```

I imagine that the _featured array is an array of PFObjects.
It looks like you are trying to implicitly cast the PFObject to an NSString. If your search functionality is searching for "name", for example, you should do your comparison to name:

```
for (PFObject *tempObj in _featured) { // or perhaps Featured
        NSComparisonResult result = [tempObj[@"name"] compare:searchString options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchString length])];
    if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
        [filteredContentList addObject:tempObj];
    }
}
```

Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Doesn't really work. It does not crash, but when I search, all the same cells are still there

Comment: Oh, I found it. In the textDidChange-method I wrote [self.tableView reloadData];, which should be [self.collectionView reloadData];. Thanks man, your code worked!

Comment: Is this in a UICollectionView or a UITableView?

Comment: Awesome, that's what I just saw. Good deal! I edited your question to use a collectionView instead, as that is less relevant to the bug you experienced.

Comment: Hm, but now for some reason when I search, it always (and only) returns the first row in the collection view, even if the object doesn't contain any of the searched letters...

Comment: That may be because your for loop in (void)searchTableList is not finished before [self.collectionView reloadData] is called at the end of your textDidChange method. I would try adding [self.collectionView reloadData] to the end of your (void)searchTableList method to see if that works. In general, you should look for ways to improve the functionality of this ViewController, and make sure that isSearching is set appropriately. It seems to me that the functionality of your SearchBarCancel and Search buttons might need a glance-over.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75876/discussion-between-tracifycray-and-benhameen).