# iOS 8.4.1 string compare is working but in iOS 9.3.2 it is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, string-comparison

[PFObject compare:options:range error when searching parse.com class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783157/pfobject-compareoptionsrange-error-when-searching-parse-com-class)

My code is similar to above link. it is working in iOS 8.4.1 but it is crashing in iOS 9.3.2

```
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithCString:combined_name encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSComparisonResult result = [name compare : searchText
                                  options : (NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)
                                    range : NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
if (result == NSOrderedSame)
{
    [self.list addObject:name];
}
```

In the above code combined_name is character array. Guide me.

I am using above code in following method.

```
- (void) updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *) searchController
```

Crashing exactly in compare method.

The screenshot is

[image]

Comment: Show the complete crash log.

Comment: When it crashes, what's the error message?

Comment: I have attached screen shot. crashing exactly in compare: method.

Answer (score 0):

NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length]) is causing problem.

Below code is working fine.

```
NSComparisonResult result = [name compare : searchText
                                  options : (NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)
                                    range : [name rangeOfString: searchText options : (NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)]];
```